# Autodesk Viewer Markup extension - can't compile from sources

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to achieve similar viewer annotations like official demo:
[lvm-react](https://lmv-react.herokuapp.com/embed?id=560c6c57611ca14810e1b2bf&extIds=Viewing.Extension.StateManager;Viewing.Extension.Markup3D&options=%27%7B%22showPanel%22:%22true%22,%22stateId%22:%22a9f227f6154286f00c7%22%7D%27)

I read official blog post and use files from Autodesk Extensions github:
http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/04/markup3d-sample-for-view-data-api.html

But I can't compile extensions from sources (create bundle.js). Tried just npm install, but there are many errors like:

```
ERROR in ./src/Viewing.Extension.VisualReport/PieChart/PieChart.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'EventsEmitter' in MY_FILES
```

and

```
ERROR in ./src/Viewing.Extension.StateManager/Viewing.Extension.StateManager.scss
Module parse failed: /MY_PATH/library-javascript-viewer-extensions-master/src/Viewing.Extension.StateManager/Viewing.Extension.StateManager.scss Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

I also installed webpack using npm, but without result, there are still many errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a few loaders missing from the webpack build production config. It is fixed now and you should be able to build all extensions. Please use the latest version from the repo.

When testing your extensions, I recommend you use ***npm run build-dev*** command, so the generated extensions files will not be minified and have source-map enabled, so you can easily debug them in browser console. When building for production, you can use ***npm run build-prod***.

You can also remove the various entries from the webpack config to build only the extensions you are interested in, for example:

```
module.exports = {

    devtool: 'eval-source-map',

    entry: {

      'Viewing.Extension.Markup3D':
        './src/Viewing.Extension.Markup3D/Viewing.Extension.Markup3D.js',
    },

    // ... rest of the config ...
```

You may also want to change the output path, in my config the output is outside of the extensions directory, directly in the project using them:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../App/dynamic/extensions'),
    filename: "[name]/[name].js",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "[name]",
    watch: true
  },
```

In addition to including the extension file to your project, you should also make sure that you include the babel polyfill (from node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js) before any extension script.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any further trouble using those extensions.